# PHP How to display multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that i have pulled back from salesforce using their API:

```
SObject Object
(
    [type] => [fields] => [Contacts] => stdClass Object
    (
        [done] => 1 [queryLocator] => [records] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Id] => [AccountId] => 0015800000XXXX12 [Name] => Test Client
            )
        )
        [size] => 1
    )
    [Name] => Marcellus House
)
```

I also did a var_dump:

```
object(SObject)#5 (4)
{
    ["type"]=> NULL
    ["fields"]=> NULL
    ["Contacts"]=> object(stdClass)#7 (4)
    {
        ["done"]=> bool(true)
        ["queryLocator"]=> NULL
        ["records"]=> array(1)
        {
            [0]=> object(stdClass)#8 (3)
            {
                ["Id"]=> NULL
                ["AccountId"]=> string(18) "0015800000XXXX12"
                ["Name"]=> string(16) "Test Client"
            }
        }
        ["size"]=> int(1)
    }
    ["Name"]=> string(15) "Marcellus House"
}
```

I am using the code below to display the Name: Marcellus House, but am struggling to display the other 2 fields in the array [AccountId] => 0015800000XXXX12 and [Name] => Test Client

```
foreach ($Response->records as $RecordSet)
{
    echo $RecordSet->Name;
}
```

I would like to all the data as follows.

```
foreach ($Response->records as $RecordSet)
{
    echo $RecordSet->Name;
    echo $RecordSet->AccountId;
    echo $RecordSet->Name;
}
```

But struggling to get this to work... Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: What isn't working? - What errors are you getting?

Comment: Why does it not behave as you want it to, what is the desired output and what are you getting?

Comment: Your other 2 fields are in another array  ID.

Comment: The above array has 3 value i want to pull out, Marcellus House, 0015800000XXXX12 and Test Client. I can display Marcellus House, but unable to display the other 2 values. i dont get any errors, just blanks

Comment: does my answer works?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more foreach

```
foreach ($Response->records as $RecordSet) 
{
    $accountid = "";
    $name = "";
    foreach($RecordSet->records as $record)
    {
        $accountid = $record['AccountId'];
        $name = $record['Name'];
    }
    echo $RecordSet->Name;
    echo $accountid;
    echo $name;
}
```

Comment: This does not work, you are overwriting $accountid and therefor will only get the last. The second foreach loop only gets the values of the last set of the array...

Comment: he is trying to echo only within the loop, I belive. It will work in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the above doesn't work, i'm still only getting the $RecordSet->Name; as before, but not the other 2 fields. I am sure the second foreach is either not running or not correct as its not looping through the array at all as i just added a echo '1'; in that array and nothing displayed.

Comment: @user1315422 updated the code, records array is in queryLocator. check again.

Comment: Many thanks for the code update, but still have the same issue, only the $RecordSet->Name; is displaying...

Comment: print_r($RecordSet) in first loop right after loop start and update the result in question.

Comment: Thats when i get the above: SObject Object ( [type] => [fields] => [Contacts] => stdClass Object ( [done] => 1 [queryLocator] => [records] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Id] => [AccountId] => 0015800000XXXX12 [Name] => Test Client ) ) [size] => 1 ) [Name] => Marcellus House )

Comment: Nothing displays now, not even the Marcellus House field. Just a blank screen, so that broke the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($Response->records as $RecordSet)
{
    echo $RecordSet->Name;
    echo $RecordSet->Contacts->records[0]->AccountId;
    echo $RecordSet->Contacts->records[0]->Name;
}
```

This should work. The Account id and Name are further nested in this object. I edited your post to make it much more readable, in fact I would ALWAYS suggest you use var dump surronded by a pre element, like this:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($yourVariable);
echo "</pre>";
```

Then you can see the structure and simple build the path you need to go to access the information you need. In this case you have to "go" to Contacts, then records. Since records is an array with only the index 0 you can simply say records[0] and "go" to the object stored in it which contains your desired information.

If this doe snot help you please let me know.